# how to allow user to input results in Array using java?

Tags: java

I want to allow the user to enter a number of race results (A minimum of 2 participants and a maximum of 7) I feel that I could use a much shorter code, (I am a beginner of Java only 2 months so any recommendation would be highly useful! thank you
Code below:

```
int entrants = 0;
String[][] runners = new String[2][2];
boolean valid = false; //this is for the initial number of runners question - it will stay false and keep us in the loop until a number between 2-7 is entered
System.out.println("Please enter the number of runners for this race (2 to 7 entrants permitted)");
entrants = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

while(valid == false){

    if(entrants < 2) {
        System.out.println("You need at least 2 runners for a race, please re-enter the number of runners");
        entrants = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    } else if (entrants > 7) {
        System.out.println("You have entered too many runners for this race (max runners is 7). Please re-enter the number of runners");
        entrants = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    } else {
        System.out.printf("You have entered %d runners\n", entrants);
        runners = new String[entrants][2];
        valid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check against both limits (2 and 7) in the same condition and have 1 common error message if the input is wrong

Comment: Always format and indent your code correctly. You're posting on a public forum, it should be easy for us to read your code.

Comment: I'd also use a do-while loop that reads input, validates the input, prints a message and finally sets `valid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's completely refactor the code.

I've made a single functional change to the code: I repeatedly ask the initial question instead of asking to re-enter. That makes it even more simple.

```
// --- only *declare* entrants, don't assign it an initial value that you don't want
int entrants;
// --- get rid of that pesky warning you get if you don't close `Scanner` instances
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // --- we'll just use a break statement to make the while loop a lot easier
    while(true) {
        //  --- this is the question that gets (re-) asked
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of runners for this race (2 to 7 entrants permitted)");

        // --- only now we assign a possible value
        // --- note that you normally first test for presence using hasNextInt!
        entrants = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        // --- nothing wrong with the original if statement
        if (entrants < 2) {
            System.out.println("You need at least 2 runners for a race.");
        } else if (entrants > 7) {
            System.out.println("You have entered too many runners for this race (max runners is 7).");
        } else {
            // --- use a clear comment *why* you break, this is an exit point for the loop after all
            // we've found a correct number of entrants
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.printf("You have entered %d runners\n", entrants);
// --- there was absolutely no reason to define or initialize the array before...
String[][] runners = new String[entrants][2];
```

Of course, to make the code actually smaller, remove the comments starting with `---`.

Comment: thank you very much! you've been very helpful

Comment: Having `new Scanner` in the code of a method leads to unwanted buffering. Better declare it as a final field somewhere, maybe even static.

Comment: @RolandIllig As long as you close it that's not a problem, and that's exactly the kind of BS optimization that you *don't* want. Keep it nice and local, then it gets cleaned up when it is not necessary anymore.

Comment: And what if the scanner has already read the next few lines that I passed via `stdin` from a file? They will be lost when the scanner is closed.

Comment: Well, in that case it needs to be kept open. But I cannot make design decisions for hypothetical applications with made up requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of lines that do the same thing and which with a little rearranging can be consolidated:

```
int entrants = 0;
String[][] runners = null; //no need to create an array that you'll be throwing away
boolean valid = false; //this is for the initial number of runners question - it will stay false and keep us in the loop until a number between 2-7 is entered
System.out.println("Please enter the number of runners for this race (2 to 7 entrants permitted)");

do {
  //read the input
  entrants = input.nextInt();
  input.nextLine();

  //validate (we'll keep your messages)
  if(entrants < 2) {
    System.out.println("You need at least 2 runners for a race, please re-enter the number of runners");      
  } else if (entrants > 7) {
    System.out.println("You have entered too many runners for this race (max runners is 7). Please re-enter the number of runners");    
  } else {
    System.out.printf("You have entered %d runners\n", entrants);

    //create the array and set the exit condition
    runners = new String[entrants][2];
    valid = true;
  }
} while (!valid);
```

Note the use of a do-while which is like a while-loop but evaluates the condition *after* an iteration, i.e. the loop body is run at least once.

Further improvements could include putting the constraints into constants (i.e. min = 2 and max = 7) instead of having them in all over your code.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I will take it into consideration

Comment: There is absolutely no need to initialize the variables to `0` or `null` whatsoever or to declare `runners` before `entrants` has been established. Java is perfectly capable of establishing that the variable gets initialized before it is used. Initializing to `null` or to an invalid value such as zero is just *asking* for runtime problems.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica you're right. However, I tried to avoid confusion by changing that as well and I wanted to keep as much of the original code as possible so I just replaced the initialization of the array with that `null`. You're right in that `runners` could be declared and initialized after the loop - I'll just leave the design issues for another time :)

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica & Thomas thank you